# How to create vue template code from AST.Like @babel/generator convert ast to code

Tags: vue.js, babeljs

- 1. Hope to provide a function like generate

```js
import { parse, generate } from '@vue/compiler-sfc'
import templateStr from './components/Script.vue?raw'
const parseResult = parse(templateStr)
const output = generate(parseResult) // vue file template code: `<script>...</script><template><div>...<div></template>`
```

I searched through the issues of vuejs, but couldn't find what I wanted. Are there any similar libraries or examples that can achieve Vue code conversion?

- 2.This is what I found @babel/generator

```js
const { parse } = require('@babel/parser');
const generate = require('@babel/generator').default;
const traverse = require('@babel/traverse').default;

const code = 'let a = 1;';
const ast = parse(code);

traverse(ast, {
    enter(path) {
        if (path.isIdentifier({ name: 'a' })) {
            path.node.name = 'b';
        }
    },
});

const output = generate(ast, {}, code);
```